# Is it possible to detect when Google Maps has rejected the API key?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to debug an intermittent alert that is opened by the Google Maps API. The alert contains the following message:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

I can't reproduce it, but I want to log it from JavaScript if it happens again. How can I do that?

Comment: Possibly related to: [Google maps javascript API V3 key disabled on certain computers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056809/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-key-disabled-on-certain-computers)

Answer (score 1):

You can check using the Google Maps API console https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1

**Update**

I found this thread on Google's dev forum which might help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/YgYdJ04hcZI

Comment: Thanks, but I meant in JavaScript, at the exact moment the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. Unfortunately it doesn't give access to any information from the map instance (e.g. what API key was actually used?)

Comment: hmm sorry I'm not sure then